# Remove item from Select2 is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a drop-down (select) to which I apply a `.select2()`. Now I'm trying to remove/add a option from the drop-down by mark/unmark a checkbox and it's not working. This is the HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="lives_in_css" name="orders[lives_in_ccs]" id="orders_lives_in_ccs">

<select class="shipping_from form-control toSelect2 select2-offscreen" required="required" name="orders[shipping_from]" id="orders_shipping_from" tabindex="-1" title="" data-bv-field="orders[shipping_from]">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-- SELECCIONAR --</option>
    <option value="MRW">MRW - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>
    <option value="DOMESA">DOMESA - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>
    <option value="ZOOM">GRUPO ZOOM - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>
</select>
```

And this is the jQuery code I made for this purpose:

```
$('.lives_in_ccs').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(".shipping_from option[value='MRW']").remove();
        $(".shipping_from").select2("val", "DOMESA");
    } else {
        $(".shipping_from").prepend('<option value="MRW">MRW - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>');
        $(".shipping_from").select2("val", "MRW");
    }

    console.log(this.checked);

    $(".secure_shipping").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

What's wrong in my code? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLto9nnv/) is jsFiddle to play with

Comment: You have a typo. `.lives_in_ccs` --> `.lives_in_css`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I have updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLto9nnv/1/) but still not working take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking to detach the given list item, and then reattach it when the checkbox is unchecked?  I am unfamiliar with select2, but the following does that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toSelect2').select2();
    var detachedMember;
    $('.lives_in_css').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            detachedMember = $('option[value="MRW"]').detach();
        } else {
            $('option[value=""]').after(detachedMember);
        }
        $(".secure_shipping").toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLto9nnv/5/)